# Codeigniter - Script execution slow - How to trace the right Controller and Method?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
 WARNING: [pool www] child 1911, script 'index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") executing too slow (1.016344 sec), logging
```

Everything in codeigniter is running from index.php
So how can i find which controller and method makes the slow execution?

Is there a way to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/benchmark.html to get their run time for a specific method

Comment: Super! This is what i want